# Error: Ninguna instancia del constructor coincide con la lista de argumentos

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy realizando un programa en C++ para Arduino. Éste es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "SerialClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Serial* Arduino = new Serial("COM6"); //El error se marca en esta linea de codigo

    while (Arduino->IsConnected()) {
        char palabra[] = "";
        scanf("%d", &palabra);
        if (palabra != NULL) {
            cout << palabra << endl;
            Arduino->WriteData(palabra, sizeof(palabra) - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

No sé cuál es el problema o por qué me marca este error:

> ninguna instancia del constructor "Serial::Serial" coincide con la lista de argumentos. Los tipos de argumento son: (const char [5])

¿Cómo puedo solucionar ese problema?

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema no se como solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de SerialClass.h? ¿Es propio o lo obtuviste de algún sitio online? (que puedas compartir) El error dice que el constructor de la clase Serial pide una cadena de 5 caracteres, pero le estás pasando una cadena de 4 caracteres ("COM6").

Comment: @JohnForero si tienes el mismo error, ¿puedes compartir un enlace a SerialClass.h?